# How to use android monkey

Tags: android, shell, adb, monkey

I am a little confused on how to actually use `monkey`, i thought you were supposed to power on your emulator and go into terminal editor and type:

```
$ adb shell monkey -p insert.my.package.name.here -v 500
```

since that did not work (error, `adb: permission denied`)

i tried `monkey -p insert.blah.blah -v 500` and this comes up that it has been killed, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

It's probably trying to talk to a device over your USB port.

You probably just need to add an `-e` in there to tell adb to connect to the emulator:

```
$ adb shell monkey -p insert.my.package.name.here -v 500
```

(Or `-s serialnum` if you have more than one emulator running.)

See [Directing commands](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#directingcommands) in the ADB docs.

Comment: Thank you for your response, my actual problem was that i was using the terminal editor right on the emulator itself i didn't think you would have to run it through command prompt aswell

Answer (score 0):

It's well explained here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/cmds/monkey/README.NETWORK.txt

it's a tool for testing apps, and the port indicates which porto to connect (binds to localhost) to issue remote commands